# Is an Anarchosocialist a valid political term?

Tags: terminology, socialism, anarchism

I once heard Noam Chomsky describe himself as one. I have never heard the term before.  If it is a valid term, what does it mean beyond the obvious mash up?

Comment: Do you have any context for his self-description? I'm used to hearing [*anarcho-syndicalist*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-syndicalism#Noam_Chomsky) instead.

Comment: Mr. Chomsky said he was a anarchosocialist in answer to a question about his political views.

Comment: Is there anything specific that you seek in an answer that isn't covered by Wikipedia article? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_anarchism

Comment: No, anarchy is related to a state of liberty with no order. It is correctly referred to as Anarcho-Socialism.

Comment: -1, and I'm voting to close because (1) most importantly, "valid" is not defined and is in the eye of the beholder; (2) what it means is fully covered in relevant Wikipedia article. There is a seed of a good question here but not as asked.

Comment: @WilliamO'day No, anarchy (as a political system) is not (or at least not usually) "a state of liberty with no order." Anarchy can be very highly ordered (or not); it's concerned more with the  _source_ rather than the _form_ of power. I go into more detail in [my answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/76496/18471).

Comment: @user4012 I think if you read "valid" as "meaningful" (as in, "makes a meaningful distinction") the question is quite reasonable. And SE in general does not dictate that if you can find the answer on Wikipedia (or via other sources) it should not be answered here. In fact, in Politics.SE we specifically ask that answers are supported by external sources.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, anarcho-socialist is a valid term in political science.It refers to communities that organize along communitarian grounds without an overarching set of governmental institutions, and is usually opposed to anarcho-individualist or anarcho-liberalist theories, which base themselves on mutual interactions of individuals. One might think here of the ideal form of communism (not the state-authoritarian forms of communism we generally find in practice).

Philosophical anarchism generally aims at some sort of trans-government mutuality — an abstract form of social contract theory — in which people voluntarily commit to maintain certain rules of social order without the need for force or punishment. The various flavors of anarchism come from the ways in which that 'mutuality' is conceptualized: whether it arises through market forces, moral obligation, social indebtedness, common effort and labor, etc... It is idealistic and utopian as a rule.

Answer (score 2):

*Author's note: if you comment, please try to avoid discussing your (or
anybody else's) personal value judgements on ideas about who should have
power, how production surplus and rent should be distributed, and the like.
Such discussion adds more heat than light when one is merely trying to
describe the philosophies between the systems in question. I certainly have
my biases, and some may come out in this answer, but I don't ask that you
agree with any you should happen to see; if you do disasgree, take it as
granted that I accept your value judgements as valid and that you think my
value judgements are wrong.*

Yes, "anarcho-socialist" is not only a valid term, but a necessary one to
describe what sort of anarchist someone is amongst the extremely broad
range of forms of anarchism.

[Anarchism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchism) is described by Wikipedia as, "a political philosophy and
movement that is skeptical of all justifications for authority and seeks to
abolish the institutions they claim maintain unnecessary coercion and
hierarchy." Chomsky describes it in similar terms in [this group discussion
at McMaster university](https://youtu.be/2G6kf7XM9Nk?t=21) (0:21):

> Anarchism covers lots of different things. If there's one leading
> principle which unifies them it's a simple one: it's based on the
> assumption that any...structure of authority and domination...has to
> justify itself: none of them are self-justifying.

Note carefully that this does *not* mean that anarchists never accept
authority and even coercion: it means only that the anarchists together
must agree that *delegating* power to that authority is a useful compromise
to achieve their aims.

The level of authority and coercion considered "justified" will often be
highly dependent on other, orthogonal political views, as well as the
particular situations that an anarchist group finds itself in from time to
time.

As just one example, should an anarchist society be faced by an external
threat that could destroy their society, they might agree that in order to
fight this threat in what they believe is the most efficient way they
should set up a conventional, very authoritarian military with significant
power over almost all of society, along the lines of what the western
nations did in World War II. If doing this is mutually agreed upon by the
members of that society, and later change in this form of government is not
precluded, this is continues to be an anarchy, despite having on the
surface having an authoritarian form at that particular moment. The key
here is that the members of the system *voluntarily* set up an authority
and gave it specific power, and still have the ability to remove that
authority when they feel it's right to do so.

It may help to think of anarchism vs. archism as a third spectrum, or at
least flavour, to be added to the classic left vs. right and libertarian
vs. authoritarian grid. Whereas the libertarian/authoritarian spectrum is
concerned with *power ideology,* such as how much concentration of power
there should be and where it should lie, the anarchism/archism spectrum is
concerned with the *source* of the power, rather than the concentration of
it. This is indeed a quite subtle distinction, but the examples below I
hope will illuminate it.

Anarchism is often thought to be a form of socialism that falls within the
left and libertarian corner of the grid, and this is indeed where the
"anarchosocialist" philosophy lies. A primary point of socialist economic
philosophy is [social ownership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_ownership) of some part of the group's wealth.
This might be, for example, that the surplus generated from land (extracted
as [economic rent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_rent)) should in whole or in part be returned to the
community in some form. (This can be done via a wide range of means, from
taxation to full-on public ownership of land; even "socialism" itself is a
spectrum, not a point.)

But we could also combine anarchism with a more right-wing libertarian
philosophy to get [anarcho-capitalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-capitalism), which, "seeks to abolish
centralized states in favor of stateless societies with systems of private
property enforced by private agencies, the non-aggression principle, free
markets and the right-libertarian interpretation of self-ownership, which
extends the concept to include control of private property as part of the
self." (Chomsky describes the vast difference between this and his
preferred societal structure in [Chomsky refutes "libertarian" "anarcho"-
capitalism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxPUvQZ3rcQ); he also illuminates some of the issues with the term
"libertarian," which has had rather different meanings in the U.S. now vs.
elsewhere at other times, asking and answering the question "How can I call
myself a libertarian socialist?")

As well as the huge difference between these on the left/right spectrum,
you might feel you also notice some difference between the two on the
libertarian/authoritarian spectrum: anarcho-socialism seems to limit
theoretical personal (economic) freedom¹ much more than anarcho-capitalism
does, and thus seems more authoritarian.

This is where the distinction I mentioned above between anarchy/archy and
libertarian/authoritarian appears: anarchy is concerned not so much with
the actual amount of personal freedom you have in its various dimensions
(though it usually defaults towards increasing it without countervailing
reason) but with your *agreement* to the levels of various kinds of
personal freedom versus other benefits you can get from society.

For comparison, it's also possible to have a very right-wing, economically
libertarian society that still has an authoritarian core that can not be
changed: there might be a ruler that dictates economic libertarianism who
cannot be changed or removed. Less anarchic libertarians might be ok with
this because they're concerned only that they have the particular freedoms
they value, and they're not too concerned about from whose authority (their
own or others') those freedoms come.

---

<sup>¹ I say "theoretical" because obviously a poor person within such a
system will have much less freedom in practice than a rich person will. How
important you think this is is a value judgement, but surely we can all
agree that "I can keep all wealth I gain through whatever means and spend
it how I want" is indeed greater personal economic freedom for that person
than "some of the wealth I gained has to go back to the society within
which I gained it," regardless of whether we think of that as a good or a
bad thing.</sup>

Comment: While I believe in respecting people's political self-identification, the definitions and ideas related to anarchism that you are discussing there seem strange to me. You say that a key distinguishing characteristic of anarchism is expecting power structures to justify themselves on the basis of their benefits to society. But many adherents of most political philosophies think exactly the same thing. The Stalinist believes that an top-down authoritarian government can be justified (and should be voluntarily adopted) because it will produce a classless society that will benefit everyone.

Comment: The democratic socialist believes that a strong social welfare state can and should voluntarily be adopted because it will improve societal equity, solidarity, and well-being. And so on and so forth. Many people who would not describe themselves as anarchists, and whom most anarchists would not describe as anarchists, believe that a power structure should be voluntarily adopted by society and justified by its benefits.

Comment: You also say that an *authoritarian military government* can be anarchist as long as it can in theory be changed in the future. But then, most forms of modern government can be considered anarchist: they are nearly all defined in terms of constitutions or bodies that can be changed by public consensus. That seems like a strange definition to me. For instance, Portland, Oregon held a vote earlier this year on changing its form of government. Does that make it an anarchist city?

Comment: Or take Spain. The current form of government was decided upon in a referendum in 1978 with overwhelming approval. That is, the voters voluntarily decided to delegate their power to a parliamentary monarchy, and there is (in theory) nothing preventing another referendum to eliminate that form of government and replace it with another. Is Spain an anarchist country?

Comment: @Obie2.0 It hadn't occurred to me that someone might consider Stalin's power to be justified in the same way that anarchist societies justify power. I've rewritten paragraph six to clarify that the power must be _delegated_ by the group as a whole; certainly that was not how Stalin got his power! ¶ You are right that democratic systems do tend toward the "anarchy" side on the anarchy/archy spectrum. "Anarchy," just like "socialism" or "authoritarianism," is not an on/off binary. Your mistake in several comments above is in asking, "is X anarchy or not?" as if it can be only one or the other.

Comment: @cjs Wow U.S. conservatives really have devastated the political terminology of left wing ideologies. Like the classical left right scheme is about social hierarchies. Left wing no hierarchies mutual coexistence or cooperation as equals and right wing strong social hierarchies with people having "their place". Anarchism being the most left with no social hierarchies authoritarianism moving you progressively to the right. Of course it's a hard sell to defend social economical and political inequality so instead U.S. right wingers call it "economic freedom" which is not universal

Comment: @cjs So no capitalism and it's social, economic and political inequality are incompatible with the absence of social hierarchies in which no person can rule other people (=anarchy). So yes most classical anarchists would therefore be socialists to the point where the term would be synonymous, in the meaning that they would argue that the means of production should be owned by the members of society and not by individuals who can exploit that power to rule others. Also I'm not making this up all of this can literally be found in wikipedia.

Comment: @haxor789 You appear to wish to compress three dimensions of difference into two, and thus claim that anarcho-capitalism can't exist. Yet it does, as you can [literally see on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-capitalism).

Comment: @cjs unless your dimensions are linearly separable the addition of new dimensions doesn't add more information. Also anarcho-capitalism does exist but is a form of capitalism NOT anarchism. And it's literally stated in that article: "Anarcho-capitalism is also distinguished from anarchism, an anti-capitalist movement that opposes unnecessary coercion and hierarchy" ... "Unlike anarchists, anarcho-capitalists support private property and private institutions.". So they use the anarcho more as a fancy way of saying "unregulated".

Comment: @haxor789 You've clearly not read or didn't understand my answer; I explain the third anarchic/archic dimension and how it's different from the libertarian/authoritarian. And sure, "anarcho-capitalism" has "anaracho" in the name because it's the opposite of anything to do with anarchy. You've got a real good grasp on things there.

Comment: @cjs First of all you seem to have your Greek wrong, the word you're searching for isn't "ἀρχή" or "arche" in the latin alphabet, which means beginning like in "Archeology" but "ἄρχω" or "archo" which means "to rule" like in "monarchy" (mono=one, archy=ruler). So Anarcho or Anti-archos is the fundamental rejection of the concept of rulership. That's why it rejects social hierarchies because it wants to rid itself of positions of default authority where one person can rule over other people. That's the prime motivation and it's social economic and political demands follow from that.

Comment: @cjs So historically anarchism has been an continuous to be anti-capitalist and socialist and this includes all branches from the individualists to the collectivists. Because under capitalism an unequal distribution of capital means power. The market doesn't decide, capital does and if capital rests in few hands, you've got a oligarchy or plutocracy which are incompatible with AN-archy. So yes anarcho-capitalism is an oxymoron and it's fairly recent one as neo-cons invented it in the 60s to confuse the hippies with talks about "liberty" while doing regular authoritarian bullshit.

Comment: @cjs and again I'm not making this up: "One gratifying aspect of our rise to some prominence is that, for the first time in my memory, we, 'our side,' had captured a crucial word from the enemy. 'Libertarians' had long been simply a polite word for left-wing anarchists, that is for anti-private property anarchists, either of the communist or syndicalist variety. But now we had taken it over." Murray Rothbard (Rothbard was a founder and leading theoretician of anarcho-capitalism and a central figure in the 20th-century American libertarian movement.)

Comment: @haxor789 Thanks for the correction the etymology; I've fixed that. As for "rejection of the concept of rulership," many modern libertarians feel that having economic power is not the same as ruling someone and thus they are effectively minimising rulership even as they concentrate economic power. And this again, all comes clear if you admit to the idea of a spectrum focusing on "agreement on power" rather than just assuming that if one demands justification for power, there can be only one possible justification for it that anybody could agree upon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140495/discussion-between-haxor789-and-cjs).

Answer (score 2):

It's a rather uncommon term, like Wikipedia would only use it as a synonym for [libertarian socialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libertarian_socialism). But if you mean whether it would make sense, then yes.

[Socialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialism#Politics) is a broad umbrella term which includes: "anarchism, communism, the labour movement, Marxism, social democracy, and syndicalism".

One objection might be that in the [19th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definition_of_anarchism_and_libertarianism#Relation_with_socialism) anarchism and socialism were used interchangeably so that it would be unnecessarily double the words.

Recently (1960s) apparently U.S. conservatives tried to take over the term Libertarian and establish one called "Anarcho-Capitalism". As this quote from Murray Rothbard (apparently famous "libertarian" figure and found of anarcho-capitalism) exemplifies:

> "One gratifying aspect of our rise to some prominence is that, for the
> first time in my memory, we, 'our side,' had captured a crucial word
> from the enemy. 'Libertarians' had long been simply a polite word for
> left-wing anarchists, that is for anti-private property anarchists,
> either of the communist or syndicalist variety. But now we had taken
> it over."

These attempts are sometimes falsely attributed to individual anarchism but either side rejects the other.

> [Anarcho-capitalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-capitalism) is also distinguished from anarchism, an anti-capitalist movement that opposes unnecessary coercion and hierarchy, and social anarchism, a branch of anarchism that sees individual freedom as interrelated with mutual aid. Unlike anarchists, anarcho-capitalists support private property and private institutions

> Traditional anarchist schools of thought oppose and reject capitalism, and consider "anarcho-capitalism" to be a contradiction in terms,[34][35][36] although some, including anarcho-capitalists and right-libertarians, have argued that anarcho-capitalism is a form of anarchism.[37][38][39][40] Anarcho-capitalism is usually seen as part of the New Right

> [In both its](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-capitalism#Anarchism) social and individualist forms, anarchism is usually considered an anti-capitalist[112][113] and radical left-wing or far-left[114][115][40] movement that promotes libertarian socialist economic theories such as collectivism, communism, individualism, mutualism and syndicalism.[116] Because anarchism is usually described alongside libertarian Marxism as the libertarian wing of the socialist movement and as having a historical association with anti-capitalism and socialism, anarchists believe that capitalism is incompatible with social and economic equality and therefore do not recognize anarcho-capitalism as an anarchist school of thought.

> Anarcho-capitalists are distinguished from the dominant anarchist tradition by their relation to property and capital. While both anarchism and anarcho-capitalism share general antipathy towards power by government authority, the latter exempts power wielded through free-market capitalism.

> Rothbard argued that anarcho-capitalism is the only true form of anarchism—the only form of anarchism that could possibly exist in reality as he maintained that any other form presupposes authoritarian enforcement of a political ideology such as "redistribution of private property", which he attributed to anarchism.

And those are only from the anarcho-capitalist article. So it's safe to say that despite the similarity in name Anarchism and anarcho-Capitalism have pretty little in common and are generally using different definitions of anarchism and have vastly different goals and that the socialist branch of anarchism is the original one.

And although there is a soft and/or hard split in anarchism between individualists and collectivists they neither claims Ancaps on their side and again Ancaps reject both of those. So to group them in the same category would be a disservice to both.

Answer (score -3):

As anarchism is a subset of socialism the term feels very odd. 
[image]

Anarchism belongs in the lower left quadrant of this chart.

Comment: Not really. Anarchism and socialism have some commonalities (as well as politiccal alignments) but they are very distinct systems. Anarchism is a political system implying lack of government (with no direct economic component in general), whereas socialism is mostly an economic (and political) system with centralized economy planning, and a government by the "proletarians and peasants" in theory and Party elite and bureaucrats in practice).

Comment: @DVK You are thinking of the authoritarian socialism. Anarchism belongs to the libertarian socialism branch.

Comment: I still posit that libertarian socialism is an oxymoron, but that's offtopic. My main critique is that you're conflating purely political idea with socio-**economic** one.

Comment: @DVK, which is the purely political one?

Comment: And -1. Pretending the "true anarchy" debate is settled is quite intellectually dishonest, regardless of your or my position on the issue. Maybe "As anarchism is considered by anarchosocialists to be a subset of socialism" would be better, even if completely vacuous.

Comment: @DVK, I just realized you're talking about anarchism vs socialism not anrchosocialism vs socialism. I should read the whole discussion next time, not just the most recent comment. :) I understand and agree now.

Comment: Totally wrong. Anarcho-capitalism is opposing socialism to the extreme.

Comment: @TellyneckBendosack Anarcho-capitalism is anarchism only in name, it has nothing to do with the political ideology of anarchism.

Comment: @TellyneckBendosack You can't really prove a negative, but you can observe that "anarcho"-capitalism has no ties with the anarchist tradition. It appears it just popped up totally independently after someone looked up anarchism in a pocket dictionary.

Comment: while this chart is very popular, it leads to many inherent contradictions.  The [3-dimensions of freedom(aka agency)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NationStates#/media/File:Updated_NS_Graph.svg), used by [Jennifer Co](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_Government), is more descriptive.

Comment: Anarchism is _not_ a subset of socialism; it's orthogonal. As I explain in my answer, archism is about source and justification of power, and, depending on the preferences of the group, might equally well produce a socialist or economically libertarian economy.

Comment: @cjs It's literally in the article for socialism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialism Anarchism is opposed to social hierarchies and the ability to rule other people. And that includes the political, economical and social sphere and any other sphere in which you would have power to rule other people though those 3 being currently the most relevant.